# MVP: Best practice to manage Activities and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp

I have an `Activity` with two `Fragments`. I decided to have one presenter for each "view". So 1 presenter for the main Activity, 1 for the first fragment, and 1 presenter for the second fragment.

I have uses-cases in which I don't know where which code goes.

- The first is where to manage fragments with fragment manager ? Do I have to do calls like "beginTransaction().add" in the activity or in his presenter ?
- The second is, when the user tap on a button in the activity, I've to do some things in the current fragment. Do I have to call the presenter of the activity which will call the fragment's method wanted, or directly in the method onClick in the activity I call this fragment's method?

PS: I don't want to use any lib/framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first is where to manage fragments with fragment manager ? Do I
>   have to do calls like "beginTransaction().add" in the activity or in
>   his presenter ?

Everything that is Android API related should be inside the `Activity`. So, `beginTransaction()` is a method of the `FragmentManager` and this is part of the Android API.  The `Activity` is the contract between your app and the operating system. The presenter should not even know that it is used for an Android app. If you press a button inside the `Activity` for instance it goes like this:

Inside event handler method which is inside your Activity you do this:
Call `activityPresenter.onButtonClicked()` and it will call `activityView.presentWhatTheButtonClickDid()`

> The second is, when the user tap on a button in the activity, I've to
>   do some things in the current fragment. Do I have to call the
>   presenter of the activity which will call the fragment's method
>   wanted, or directly in the method onClick in the activity I call this
>   fragment's method?

You would indirectly call the Fragment method via its presenter.

Inside event handler method which is inside your Activity:
Call `activityPresenter.onButtonClicked()` and it will call
`fragmentPresenter.onButtonClicked()`  and it will calls 
`fragmentView.presentResult()`

So, as you see the Activitiy's presenter needs to know the Fragment's presenter.

*You should not name your presenters with "activity" or "fragment" in its name to keep things abstract. I merely did this for simplicity.

Comment: If I understood, it means that the activity's presenter need to know the fragment's presenter ?

Comment: @deveLost exactly!

Comment: But for my first question, I have another problem :D Because all of what I do in the action, calls Android API, I can't do nothing in my presenter so... So I will have "logic" in my view, isn't it a problem With MVP Pattern ?

Comment: No, you will have all your logic inside the presenter! you only call Activity methods with the result of the logic. For example: an Activity method would be void presentList(List<Items> items). And this will do nothing more than display the list it gets. From where the list was loaded, how it was filtered and so on ... these are all things that happened in the presenter.

Comment: But in this case to be more precise, when the users taps on the button, I do something like this :

1. Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);

2. if frag.checkInputs() .... /* I can do this in my activity's present to call the fragment's presenter */

3. new Handler.postDelayed -> call another action in fragment

So what can I do in my presenter ? All of this method (except 2.) can't be execute in the presenter isn't it ?

Comment: @deveLost 1. in Activity, 2. in presenter, 3. in Activity, 4. (call another action in) in presenter 5. this calls something on the Activity then. The goal is the keep the views as stupid as possible. For this you need to sometimes make really small steps and constanty jump between presenter and Activity. Rule of thumb is the keep business logic in the Presenter and API related stuff in the Activity. Even if you just do one fragment transaction and then call a single method in this method it's ok. Do small steps.

Comment: Thx for your help, just a last case ^^ In the 2. I need to have access to inputs values from the view (fragment's view). So It will be better to call directly the frag's view which calls after the frag's presenter or to call like said the frag's presenter which calls values required from the view ?

Comment: pass the values from the views (of the fragment) to the presenter or define getters on the view (fragment), like getUsername() and call those getters inside the presenter. by the way, really good questions. I faced the same problems when I started with MVP. if you see it in practice you will get a feeling for it really fast and everything will make sense. :) you will also see then why 3 presenters are better than one in your usecase.

Comment: Oh ok thx :) But it's still a little complicated to separate view and presenter :( For example, I want to check if I've Internet. I can't do this in my presenter (because need context to call the correct method), but If I do this in my activity it will be strange, because the view had just to manage UI elements not others things :/

Comment: First you would create an Interface called "IConnectivityManager" with a method like "hasInternetConnection". Then you create a class "ConnectivityManager" which implements it. In your Activity you would create your presenter like this: new Presenter(new ConnectivityManager(this), ...). In your presenter constructor declaration your use IConnectionManager as datatype. All your presenter knows is that it deals with a IConnetionManager. It does not know that there is a context. Only the concrete implementation of IConnectionManager knows that. Basically we added an abstraction layer. :)

Comment: Ok fine... You win :D Thx you !

Comment: Just, Why in this case an interface is useful ? We can just create a class and pass it to te present, isn't it ?

Comment: @deveLost no, it's about testability. later on, you want to mock the ConnectivityManager (when you test the Presenter, which uses it as dependency) by creating a MockConnectivityManager class which implements the methods of the interface. If you would specifiy a class in the constructor of the presenter and not an interface you would need to specify a Context. This is not what you want. The mocked version should not need a context and thus your test does not need instrumentation (a running Android system) but only plain Java. :)